# How to split 2 audio signals and then mix them?

Tags: amplifier, audio, analog, signal

I'm working on a simple audio circuit which takes two different signals from mp3 players (earphones output), mix them up and outputs to an amplifier/speaker. But before mixing the signals, I need to measure the onset of Signal 1 with a microcontroller, in the case an Atmega328. I have little experience with audio and amplifiers so I don't know how to split Signal 1 from Signal 2 in order to read Signal 1 only.

I have also added a simple voltage divider for DC offset so the Atmega328 won't read negative voltages. Below a simple schematic of what I have so far:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw1wr8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: "I need to measure the onset of Signal 1 with a microcontroller", why? - Also, have you tried this circuit already? Connecting the two outputs of the mp3 players without any resistor between them?

Comment: This is for an artwork, one of the sounds playing will trigger lights, the other is background but both need to be coming out from the same speaker. I tried, it outputs the sound fine. The only issue is what to do to read just signal 1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Put 1 kΩ between *signal 1* and *audio in*
- Put 1 kΩ between *signal 2* and *audio in*
- Disconnect \$C_1\$ from *audio in*
- Connect a wire from *signal 1* to \$C_1\$

In theory you'll get 100% of *signal 1* onto A0 of the Arduino. In reality you're probably going to get 99.9%, 0.01% being random noise and signal 2. I hope you can live with that.

Comment: That's great, I don't mind if it's 100%, this will be enough for the threshold I need. I will try it today and vote for the solution later on. Thank you!